# Passing Form Params to Model in Rails3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to pass some parameters (count) from a form to a model.

The model basically creates a user X times.

In our form, we have this:

```
= f.text_field :count
```

And I can see this is submitted properly in the dev. log:

```
user"=>{"count"=>"2"}
```

I've tried this in my controller:

```
@user = User.generate(params[:count])
```

Generate is then supposed to call this in my user model:

```
def self.generate(count=10)
  count.times do
  .....
end
```

I basically need the '10' replaced with the count from form.

How can I go about this?

-- UPDATE 1 --

I've edited as below but get had to change from count to usercount because I think that's reserved in rails..

I have this in my controller:

```
@user = User.generate(params[:user][:usercount])
```

This in my user.rb:

```
attr_accessor :usercount   

def self.generate
  usercount.times do
  ...
end
```

When I submit, I get this:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  app/models/user.rb:22:in `generate'
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:38:in `new_users_create'
```

Really frustrating...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class User
  attr_accessor :count
end

@user = User.generate(params[:user][:count])
```

should work fine.

Comment: Cool, but how do I use :count in user.rb?

Comment: I'm being blonde! Does that mean I can do this: :count.times do ??!

Comment: I'll look up instance methods! It gives me an error using :count (wrong number of arguments). Sorry I didn't mark it sooner, you distracted me with your speedy replies :)

Comment: To dig into this kind of "helpers" you can do some searches for "rails virtual attributes". Really useful sometimes :)

Comment: I actually still can't get it to work. It seems to give this error "undefined method `times' for :count:Symbol"

Comment: You should remove the ":" from :count.times I guess